# Появляется огромный отступ у другого блока при добавлении картинки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

При вёрстке макета столкулся с такой вот проблемой, при добавлении картинки появляется огромный отступ между абзацом и заголовками. Как это можно исправить?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="mobile">
  <div class="mobile-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h1>akita uni dog</h1>
          <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-2">
          <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/24/a15cc09ebad58f0a8417f40f311a9509-full.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="rows">
            <div>
              <h3>Fully Responsive Design</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>High Quality Code</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>Different Headers & Layout</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте. Все верно, `h3` заголовки идут в следующем row, следовательно они появляются ниже. Как вариант: уменьшить высоту контента в первом `row`, например уменьшить высоту картинки. Можно перенести заголовки h3 в первый row, как вам здесь ответил пользователь aleksandr_hramcov. Рекомендую почитать про сетку bootstrap, как она вообще работает, так как проблема здесь именно в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="mobile">
  <div class="mobile-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-5">

          <h1>akita uni dog</h1>

          <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>

          <div>
            <h3>Fully Responsive Design</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>High Quality Code</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Different Headers & Layout</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-2">
          <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/24/a15cc09ebad58f0a8417f40f311a9509-full.png" alt="">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, достаточно глупую ошибку я допустил.